# QTextBrowser not processing CSS properly

Tags: html, css, qt, qtextbrowser

I am having problems with rendering HTML with `QTextBrowser`. It does not process some CSS properties such as tr height, table borders, etc. For instance,

This does not work: `<table style=' border: 1px solid black;'>`
This does not work: `<tr style='height: 10px'>`

The code above DOES work on Google Chrome 31.

Is there an alternative for this, or is there any trick for solving this kind of issues? Using `QWebView` could be a good choice but it does not provide an `append()` method.

Could you please suggest me something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QTextBrowser supports only a [subset of HTML and CSS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).

If you need full support use QWebView, you can emulate appending with something like this:

```
QString html = webView->page()->currentFrame()->toHtml(); //or mainFrame()
html += "Something to append";
webView->setHtml(html);
```

Comment: I will try the QWebView solution but, as I guess, performance will be slow when dealing with large HTML code.

Comment: If it's slow, try Qt5, there's a new Webkit and V8 Javascript engine from Google Chrome.